# Ability to vertically scroll outer layout within a horizontal scrollbox

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'd like to be able to scroll through my main, outer layout vertically even if my thumb (touch) is within a horizontal scrollbox (which allows me only to scroll through its items horizontally). I've already tried replacing the horizontal scrollbox with a standard TScrollBox but without luck.

Examples of this can be found in applications such as Instagram (with their stories) and Facebook. A concept image is shown below from another question whose answer isn't applicable in Delphi.

[image: Concept]

Edit: there's a component in Android called 'Nested Recycler View' that does this exact thing I'm looking for. Is there anything similar for Delphi Firemonkey?

Comment: Check this link: https://android.jlelse.eu/easily-adding-nested-recycler-view-in-android-a7e9f7f04047

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, but for Delphi Firemonkey framework, not Android Studio.

Comment: This GUI would be so easy to accomplish with HTML and CSS, speak: a website.

Comment: Have you considered using Gestures?

Answer (score 2):

have you tried awsome controls from https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe
try to build single row of main layout with tabs and slide efect